# Getting a value from list of strings

Tags: c#, .net

The entity instance here is getting a list of 10 arrays from which I need to get the value of invalid Dir.

```
var entityInstance = FacadeServiceContext.LoadEntityBaseInstances(entityName, searchParams, context: null).ToList();
if (entityInstance != null && entityInstance.Any())
{
    var invalidDirflag = entityInstance.Where(item => item.Equals(CustomConstants.ICMInvalidDIR));
    foreach (var item in entityInstance )
    {
        if( invalidDirflag.Equals(false))
         {
            var filters = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
            addHeaderFilters(filters, request);
            addLineItems(filters, (JArray)request[SourcingConstants.ClientSoCoApplicableDocumentsAttributesItemsFieldName]);
            coAppDocs.AddRange(filterDeterminedDocuments(entityInstance, filters));
        }
    } 
}
```

I get an exception with the above code:

> Enumeration yielded no results

How do I do this?

Comment: What line does the error come from?

Comment: from var invalidDirflag = entityInstance.Where(item => item.Equals(CustomConstants.ICMInvalidDIR));

Comment: Pretty sure that means your entityInstance doesn't have any elements that are equal to CustomConstants.ICMInvalidDIR. (I'm not familiar with the library classes you're working with though, so I could be wrong.) Maybe check whether the type of the elements in entityInstance are the same as the type of the CustomConstants.ICMInvalidDIR? If the types are different, that would make the .Equals() always fail.

Comment: What are you trying to do? The logic seems wrong here because you're looping over every item in the results and repeating the same action over and over, but not using any data from the item in the collection you're iterating over. It feels like you should instead be looping over the collection, then checking a condition on each item and taking an action on/with that item if a condition is true. Or, better yet, filter the list on the condition first, then take an action on/with each item in the filtered result set.

Comment: entityinstance is getting data i checked in debugger mode, its populating with 10 arrays each of which have the invalid dir attribute either as false or true.

Comment: hey, rufus. i understood your suggestion but i cannot put filters over entity instance it needs to be populated with all the data, for the first part of the code the invaliddir should be inside the for each loop. i agreee with this. but i kept it outside . becaus emy main problem now is the where query not working. regardless of everything else i need the invalidDIRfalg to be poulated with true or false. the rest i can manage

Answer (score 1):

Linq Function "Where" could return empty iteration.
Check your code line 4. Plus, "Where" Function does not return bool type.
I recommend to use "FirstOrDefault()" on line 4. If iteration is empty, variable invalidDirflag will be set to false.
See below code.

```
var entityInstance = FacadeServiceContext.LoadEntityBaseInstances(entityName, searchParams, context: null).ToList();
if (entityInstance != null && entityInstance.Any())
{
    var invalidDirflag = entityInstance.Where(item => item.Equals(CustomConstants.ICMInvalidDIR)).FirstOrDefault();
    foreach (var item in entityInstance )
    {
        if( invalidDirflag.Equals(false))
         {
            var filters = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
            addHeaderFilters(filters, request);
            addLineItems(filters, (JArray)request[SourcingConstants.ClientSoCoApplicableDocumentsAttributesItemsFieldName]);
            coAppDocs.AddRange(filterDeterminedDocuments(entityInstance, filters));
        }
    } 
}
```